# QGIS Identify export

Tags: qgis, export, csv, identify

Is it possible to make and export (to csv) from the result in the identify?  I tried the attributtabel, but I would like the info of more layers at once.

Comment: You can select it and export only the selected ones

Comment: It doesn't work, selecting in de identify results. Yes, I van copie the result of one layer, but I would like to have the result of all layers seen in the identifierwindow

Comment: No, AFAIK there's no way to copy all the results from the Identify window in one step. It *might* be possible through Python, if you're willing to read through the [PyQGIS Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html#). Or you might be able to achieve a similar result by creating a feature that intersects the features you want to Identify, and using `aggregate()` functions or a spatial join.

Comment: Thanks. I Will try that. Both, aggregate and python. So of you have a script to start with... always welcome

Comment: https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/10/31/how-to-export-attributes-from-qgis-to-a-txt-file/

Comment: from identity to blocknote... but not in QGIS3.4

Comment: Can anyone help me?